# Running dart tests as you can run go tests it in Goland

Tags: goland

I have installed the Dart plugin in Goland. It is possible to run dart tests from the UI
, as you can run go tests from the UI?

[image]

Comment: Please see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dart.html#dart_testing_applications